# What is the formula of varImp in R?

Tags: r, feature-selection, caret, rpart

I'm using varImp function(caret package) in R to get importance of variables and to select variables. I know how can i get result. This is my code and result.

```
> library("rpart")
> rpartmod3<-rpart(Creditability~.,data=ccc,method="class")
> ptree3<-prune(rpartmod3, cp=rpartmod3$cptable[which.min(rpartmod3$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
> varImp(ptree3)
 Overall
Account.Balance                   47.909620
Age..years.                        1.711184
Credit.Amount                     31.031502
Duration.in.Current.address        2.610062
Duration.of.Credit..month.        50.147777
Guarantors                         9.965751
Instalment.per.cent                8.124237
Length.of.current.employment       8.012042
Most.valuable.available.asset     31.212222
No.of.Credits.at.this.Bank         2.990769
Occupation                         4.279494
Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit 36.756420
Purpose                           48.610134
Value.Savings.Stocks              34.885005
Sex...Marital.Status               0.000000
Concurrent.Credits                 0.000000
Type.of.apartment                  0.000000
No.of.dependents                   0.000000
Telephone                          0.000000
Foreign.Worker                     0.000000
```

In this result, I want to know formular of overall. For example, t-test, Gini index or any other statistic formular.
Does anyone know fomular of varImp in decision tree????
cf)I know that if I use ?varImp, there are explanation. But, there is no decision tree's statistic formular.

Thanks you for your reply. Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm sure it's documented in caret.

Comment: https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html

Comment: Look for section on Recursive Partitioning

Comment: @PlayStarCraftWithMe Recursive Partitioning means rpart varImp???

Comment: `rpart` is an implementation for Recursive Partitioning. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @PlayStarCraftWithMe I don't know well.. Maybe you're right. So, I read that url. But.. what is the result??? There is no formular... Just explain what is the Recursive partitioning.... As I mentioned it, I want to know statistic formular like t-test ~~ ...  Anyway, I'm glad to your reply.!

Comment: There is no formula in that link because there is no formula anywhere.  You run the recursive partitioning algorithm and keep track of how much each split reduces the loss function.  That's is the "formula", or more correctly, that is how you compute it.

Comment: @MatthewDrury a ha! I got it!! You mean that varImp in rpart has no formular. Right? But, Other method like linear regression has formular, so that is posted on ?varImp. Right?